# Transfer the gas value of contract to my own address

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

What happens ?

```
    msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
```

remix.eth is just telling me

> errored: Cannot read property 'op' of undefined

Comment: Your question is incorrect. You probably mean transferring funds from the smart contract to your wallet? As the gasConsumed * gasPrice = whatYouPayForMiner and this can't be transferred.

Comment: Yes my question was about that, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {

    function () payable {
        msg.sender.transfer(msg.value);
    }

}
```

I get invalid opcode if I don't specify the function is payable.